# Stencil Buffering in elm-webgl

Tags: javascript, webgl, shader, elm

I'm trying to make a simple OpenGL program in elm-webgl. I took one of the examples that has a box that rotates around, and I wanted to use stencil testing to only render one row of pixels at a time.

I was able to achieve drawing the line I wanted, and I tried setting it up to render only on the stencil buffer. Then I set up the rendering of the cube to only pass the stencil test if for the line in the stencil buffer, but it doesn't seem to work. It just renders the cube like normal.

Here's my Elm program (modified version of [this example](https://github.com/elm-community/elm-webgl/blob/master/examples/crate.elm)):

```
import Math.Vector2 exposing (Vec2)
import Math.Vector3 exposing (..)
import Math.Matrix4 exposing (..)
import Task
import Time exposing (Time)
import WebGL exposing (..)
import WebGL exposing (FunctionCall(..), CompareMode(..), Capability(..), ZMode(..))
import Html exposing (Html)
import Html.App as Html
import AnimationFrame
import Html.Attributes exposing (width, height)


type alias Model =
  { texture : Maybe Texture
  , theta : Float
  }


type Action
  = TextureError Error
  | TextureLoaded Texture
  | Animate Time


update : Action -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Action)
update action model =
  case action of
    TextureError err ->
      (model, Cmd.none)
    TextureLoaded texture ->
      ({model | texture = Just texture}, Cmd.none)
    Animate dt ->
      ({model | theta = model.theta + dt / 10000}, Cmd.none)


init : (Model, Cmd Action)
init =
  ( {texture = Nothing, theta = 0}
  , loadTexture "/woodCrate.jpg"
    |> Task.perform TextureError TextureLoaded
  )


main : Program Never
main =
  Html.program
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , subscriptions = (\model -> AnimationFrame.diffs Animate)
    , update = update
    }


-- MESHES

crate : Drawable { pos:Vec3, coord:Vec3 }
crate =
  Triangle <|
  List.concatMap rotatedFace [ (0,0), (90,0), (180,0), (270,0), (0,90), (0,-90) ]


fmod : Float -> Float -> Float
fmod a b =
  a - (toFloat <| floor <| a / b) * b


line : Float -> Drawable { pos: Vec3 }
line theta =
  let
    y = (fmod -theta 2) - 1
  in
    Lines
      [ ({ pos = vec3 -1 y 0 } , { pos = vec3 1 y 0 })
      ]


rotatedFace : (Float,Float) -> List ({ pos:Vec3, coord:Vec3 }, { pos:Vec3, coord:Vec3 }, { pos:Vec3, coord:Vec3 })
rotatedFace (angleX,angleY) =
  let
    x = makeRotate (degrees angleX) (vec3 1 0 0)
    y = makeRotate (degrees angleY) (vec3 0 1 0)
    t = x `mul` y `mul` makeTranslate (vec3 0 0 1)
    each f (a,b,c) =
      (f a, f b, f c)
  in
    List.map (each (\x -> {x | pos = transform t x.pos })) face


face : List ({ pos:Vec3, coord:Vec3 }, { pos:Vec3, coord:Vec3 }, { pos:Vec3, coord:Vec3 })
face =
  let
    topLeft     = { pos = vec3 -1  1 0, coord = vec3 0 1 0 }
    topRight    = { pos = vec3  1  1 0, coord = vec3 1 1 0 }
    bottomLeft  = { pos = vec3 -1 -1 0, coord = vec3 0 0 0 }
    bottomRight = { pos = vec3  1 -1 0, coord = vec3 1 0 0 }
  in
    [ (topLeft,topRight,bottomLeft)
    , (bottomLeft,topRight,bottomRight)
    ]


-- VIEW

perspective : Float -> Mat4
perspective angle =
  List.foldr mul Math.Matrix4.identity
    [ perspectiveMatrix
    , camera
    , makeRotate (3*angle) (vec3 0 1 0)
    , makeRotate (2*angle) (vec3 1 0 0)
    ]

perspectiveMatrix : Mat4
perspectiveMatrix =
  makePerspective 45 1 0.01 100


camera : Mat4
camera =
  makeLookAt (vec3 0 0 5) (vec3 0 0 0) (vec3 0 1 0)

lineFunctionCalls: List FunctionCall
lineFunctionCalls =
  [ Disable StencilTest
  , Enable StencilTest
  , StencilFunc (Always, 1, 0xFF)
  , StencilMask 0xFF
  , DepthMask 0x00
  , ColorMask (0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00)
  ]

cubeFunctionCalls: List FunctionCall
cubeFunctionCalls =
  [ StencilFunc (Equal, 1, 0xFF)
  , StencilMask 0x00
  , DepthMask 0xFF
  , ColorMask (0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)
  ]

initFunctionCalls: List FunctionCall
initFunctionCalls =
  [ Enable DepthTest
  , DepthFunc Less
  ]

view : Model -> Html Action
view {texture, theta} =
  (case texture of
    Nothing ->
        []
    Just tex ->
        [ renderWithConfig lineFunctionCalls lineVertexShader lineFragmentShader (line theta) {}
        , renderWithConfig cubeFunctionCalls vertexShader fragmentShader crate { crate = tex, perspective = perspective theta }
        ]
  )
  |> WebGL.toHtmlWith initFunctionCalls [width 400, height 400]


-- SHADERS

vertexShader : Shader { pos:Vec3, coord:Vec3 } { u | perspective:Mat4 } { vcoord:Vec2 }
vertexShader = [glsl|

attribute vec3 pos;
attribute vec3 coord;
uniform mat4 perspective;
varying vec2 vcoord;

void main () {
  gl_Position = perspective * vec4(pos, 1.0);
  vcoord = coord.xy;
}

|]

lineVertexShader : Shader { pos: Vec3 } u {}
lineVertexShader = [glsl|
attribute vec3 pos;

void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.0);
}
|]

lineFragmentShader : Shader a u {}
lineFragmentShader = [glsl|
precision mediump float;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
|]


fragmentShader : Shader {} { u | crate:Texture } { vcoord:Vec2 }
fragmentShader = [glsl|

precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D crate;
varying vec2 vcoord;

void main () {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(crate, vcoord);
}

|]
```

I'm using a modified version of elm-webgl that adds a couple of function calls like `ColorMask` and `StencilMask`. These map one to one with their JavaScript WebGL counter parts.

I'm not super educated on how the stencil buffer works, and I have little experience with OpenGL. I've read two tutorials on stencil buffers: [this one](http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Stencil-testing) and [this one](https://open.gl/depthstencils), and as far as I can tell, there's no reason this shouldn't be working.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just checking but did you ask for a stencil buffer? WebGL defaults to *not* having one. You can ask for one when creating the webgl context by passing in `{stencil: true}` as the second parameter to `getContext` in JavaScript. I have no idea about elm.

Comment: That's absolutely what it was, thanks! Put that as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checking but did you ask for a stencil buffer? WebGL defaults to not having one. You can ask for one when creating the webgl context by passing in `{stencil: true}` as the second parameter to `getContext` in JavaScript.